# Archivo de texto corrupto

Tags: c, archivo

Buenas tardes, estoy realizando una practica para la universidad, el programa consiste en la creación de un bucle en el cual un proceso hijo, creado mediante fork() envíe a través de una pipe su pid al padre y acto seguido muera, el padre a continuación, introduce el pid y un salto de linea en un archivo de texto.

El número de veces que ejecutas el bucle y el nombre del archivo de texto los introduces como argumentos de la función.

El problema es que el programa creo que funciona bien pero a la hora de crear el archivo de texto lo codifica de tal manera que me es imposible leer los resultados. Os dejo el código a continuación. Gracias de antemano.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

 int pid, fd[2], estado;
 int buf[256];
 creat(argv[2], 7777);
 //printf("%d\n", f);

 pipe(fd);

 int nhijos = *argv[1] -'0';
 for(int i=0; i<nhijos; i++){
     switch(fork()){
     case 0:        //Hijo
        close (fd[0]);
        close (1);
        dup(fd[1]);
        close(fd[1]);
        pid = getpid();
        buf[1]= pid;
        write(1, buf, 2);
        write(1, "\n", 1);
        exit(0);
    case -1: 
        printf("fork");
    default:        //Padre
        close (fd[1]);
        close (0);
        dup(fd[0]);
        close(fd[0]);
        read(0, buf, 3);
        write(3, buf, 3);
        int err;
        err = wait(&estado);
    }
}
printf("Termino la ejecucion \n");
exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sin probar tu código, veo que haces

```
int buf[256];
. . .
write( 1, buf, 2 );
write( 1, "\n", 1 );
```

Haciendo eso, `write( )` estaria imprimiendo la representación binaria de un número, **no** los caracteres (dígitos) que lo forman. Además, ¿ de donde sacas que el tamaño de un `int` es `2` ? En todo caso, podría ser `write( 1, buf, sizeof( int ) );`.

Entre las varias soluciones posibles, te propongo convertir esos `int` a `caracteres`, e imprimir estos últimos. Te muestro un ejemplo funcional, fácil de *adaptar* a tu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int Number = 1024;
char string[15]; // Núm. arbitrario; caracteres máximos.
sprintf( string, "%d", Number ); // string[] = "1024\n";

write( 1, string, strlen( string ) );
write( 1, "\n", 1 );
```

Eres libre de usarlo donde quieras; o envías los caracteres correctos al padre, o envías el número y que el padre lo transforme. A gusto del consumidor.